# How can I know when the text of an editable JComboBox has been changed?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have an *editable* JComboBox where I want to take some action whenever the text is changed, either by typing or selection.  In this case, the text is a pattern and I want to verify that the pattern is valid and show the matches that result in some test data.

Having done the obvious, attach an ActionHandler, I have found that, for typing, the event seems to fire unreliably, at best (selection is fine).  And when it *does* fire as a result of typing, the text retrieved (using getEditor().getItem(), since getSelectedItem() only gets the text when it was selected from the list) seems to be the text as it was when the last event was fired - that is, it's always missing the character was typed immediately before the action event was fired.

I was expecting the action event to fire after some short delay (500ms to 1 second), but it seems immediately fired upon keying (if it is fired at all).

The only workable alternative I can think of is to simply start a 1 second timer on focus-gained, killing it on focus-lost and doing the work as the timer action if the content is different from last time.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

The code snippets are not particularly interesting:

```
find.addActionListener(this);
...
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    System.out.println("Find: "+find.getEditor().getItem());
    }
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The action listener is typically only fired when you hit enter, or move focus away from the editor of the combobox. The correct way to intercept individual changes to the editor is to register a document listener:

```
final JTextComponent tc = (JTextComponent) combo.getEditor().getEditorComponent();
tc.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);
```

The [DocumentListener interface](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) has methods that are called whenever the Document backing the editor is modified (insertUpdate, removeUpdate, changeUpdate).

You can also use an anonymous class for finer-grained control of where events are coming from:

```
final JTextComponent tcA = (JTextComponent) comboA.getEditor().getEditorComponent();
tcA.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() { 
  ... code that uses comboA ...
});

final JTextComponent tcB = (JTextComponent) comboB.getEditor().getEditorComponent();
tcB.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() { 
  ... code that uses comboB ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try.  I don't mind Swing as a whole, but sometimes working out how to get certain behavior or trap certain events is **FAR** from obvious.

Comment: OK, so putting aside the "19" levels of method call... Having added a document listener, when the event occurs I can find no way to tie it to which of the two combo-boxes were changed.  At this point, a simple timer's looking rather attractive.

Comment: I stored the last known text for the two CBs, and use that to determine which has changed when the document event is fired.  If you know how to tie the event back to the component which fired it that would be useful info - since a DocumentEvent is not a standard AWT event or java.util.EventObject.

Comment: The document doesn't really know about the component it's hooked to by design. That way you can have multiple "views" of the same document. Rather than a single DocumentListener implementation, create a separate one for each combo box. An anonymous class would probably be good here.

Comment: I added another example using anonymous classes.

Comment: @LawrenceDol (or anyone who reads this in the future) - You can store the `Document` as a field in the parent class (referring to `tc.getDocument()`).  Then, in any of the changed/remove/insert update methods of the `DocumentListener`, the `DocumentEvent.getDocument()` method will return the `Document` that is linked to the `JComboBox`.  True, you may have to have just a bit of extra logic to keep track of the fact that the two objects are associated with each other.

Answer (score -1):

You can use somthing like this:

```
JComboBox cbListText = new JComboBox();
cbListText.addItem("1");
cbListText.addItem("2");
cbListText.setEditable(true);
final JTextField tfListText = (JTextField) cbListText.getEditor().getEditorComponent();
tfListText.addCaretListener(new CaretListener() {
    private String lastText;

    @Override
    public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent e) {
        String text = tfListText.getText();
        if (!text.equals(lastText)) {
            lastText = text;
            // HERE YOU CAN WRITE YOUR CODE
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

this sounds like the best solution

```
jComboBox.getEditor().getEditorComponent().addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {    //add your hadling code here:

}    });
```

Comment: This misses changes made without using the keyboard (e. g. pasting or deleting text using the pointing device).