# How to listen what is written inside a JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

So I have a JTextArea where the user is supposed to put in a location as in town. He can put in the town but I need the String he enters to be saved for later. I don't know exactly what kind of listener to use and how to..

Comment: This question is too broad but... do some research on `DocumentListener`.

Comment: The normal mode of work with with Swing forms is that the user presses a button, and then you get the values of all the fields you need and put them where you need. So you don't need to listen to each field. Is your program supposed to do something else? If so, [edit] your question (do not use the comments for this) and add a pic of the GUI, what the user is supposed to do and what is supposed to happen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Swing: How to get TextArea value including the char just typed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137111/java-swing-how-to-get-textarea-value-including-the-char-just-typed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when end users fill out some kind of a form (eg comprised of JTextAreas), to submit / save the data they usually push some button named "Submit" or "Save" etc..
So in this case the actual listener (ActionListener) is added to the button, which once clicked you retrieve your String(s) from the JTextArea(s). 
Code example :

```
yourButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
             String aString = yourJTextArea.getText();
       }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a DocumentListener

```
JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
area.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() ......);
```